# How does git push work with android's repo tool?

Tags: android, git, github, gerrit, repository

I'm used to using `git` with a single repository. However, I've lately been dabbling with Android development and am trying to wrap my head around `repo`. I have set up some custom git repos by creating xmls in the `.repo/local_manifests` directory (I'm using repo 1.19) and `repo sync` works fine.

When I look at the custom git repos they say `# Not currently on any branch.` This looks just like when I use a command like `git checkout abcd1234` (to check out commit abcd1234) rather than `git checkout origin/master`. As far as making changes, I'm not sure how to push back to origin. Here's my normal git workflow.

```
git checkout origin/master
#make changes to working directory
git add .
git commit -m 'useful message'
#assume time has passed and there could be changes upstream
git fetch
git rebase origin/master
git push origin master
```

Now that I'm no longer technically on a branch, how can I push changes? I know there is a tool `repo upload` but I'm not exactly sure how it works. I've never used Gerrit, but maybe it would be worth setting up so other team members can review code before it gets pushed to Github. Honestly I still have a very abstract understanding of `repo` and `Gerrit`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Technically, if you do

```
git checkout origin/master
```

you immediately get into detached HEAD state.

For better or worse, this is exactly what `repo sync` does by default - such that every one of your repositories listed in manifest is in detached HEAD state after fresh `repo sync`.

Detached HEAD is perfectly normal state for `repo` - if origin/master moves forward, `repo sync` will also move your local state (effectively it does `git checkout origin/master` again).

However, this weird state is not good if you want to make your own changes and push them upstream. In this case, you can do one of the following:

```
repo start master .
```

which means start tracking branch called `master` in current project (`.`).

Alternatively, you can use (and I prefer this, actually):

```
git checkout --track origin/master
```

Both methods will give you almost identical result: you no longer will be in detached HEAD state, but on local branch which will be tracking remote branch.

At this point, you can make local commits and push them directly upstream using standard `git push` (but this may not be permitted by server policy) or you can submit for Gerrit code review (highly recommended and is default choice for most Android shops).
Once tracking branch is in place, submitting to Gerrit is as simple as

```
repo upload     # upload changes in multiple repositories at once
```

or

```
repo upload .   # upload changes in current git repo only, fast!
```

(this assumes that your manifest contains proper settings for review server).

Comment: If you track a branch so that you're no longer in detached HEAD state, then when you make changes with `git commit` and later use `repo sync` to get up to date, what happens? Does `repo` do a `git merge`, a `git rebase`, do the changes get lost, or something else?

Comment: By running `repo sync` you should never lose your local changes. If branch is tracking, depending on `repo` version it may attempt to do `git pull --rebase` or `git pull` (which effectively does merge). I prefer to override this uncertainty by running explicit `git pull --rebase` to be sure that I always rebase.

Comment: @mvp made me feel pretty safe running `repo sync`.  However, I missed the part about tracking branches.  If you aren't on a tracking branch, `repo sync` will happily discard your commits on a detached HEAD, or leave your local branch, and leave your repos pointing to the git commit specified in the manifest listed under "revision".  At least it has the courtesy to list them at the end of the `repo sync` command.  To easily get them back run `git reflog` to find them before checking them out.  The shortcut `git checkout HEAD@{1}` worked for my detached HEAD commits.

Comment: For those who use GitHub or GitLab instead of Gerrit, we added a "repo push" command: https://github.com/wavecomp/git-repo